# New ListItem with Pnp.PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a new list item in a SharePoint Online list using the Pnp.PowerShell Module in a PowerShell script.  Here is my code and the output:

```
## ... urls and security creds removed... 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $km_site -ClientId $clientid -ClientSecret $secret -WarningAction Ignore
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$projects_list = Get-PnPList "Projects"
Write-Host $projects_list.Title -ForegroundColor Green
$lci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation -ArgumentList @()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$new_item = $projects_list.AddItem($lci)
Write-Host $new_item.Id -ForegroundColor Cyan
$new_item["Title"] = $title
$new_item["Project_x0020_Code"] = $code
$new_item["_ExtendedDescription"] = $desc
$new_item["ContentTypeId"] = "0x010097F10B16E4516A4E80FC5C8FABF9BAC400AEEB05A0E486404FA588439EADC25541"
# Write-Host $new_item.FieldValues -ForegroundColor Cyan
$new_item.Update()
# $projects_list.Update()
Write-Host "Created!!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $new_item.Id -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Output:

```
Projects
-1
Created!!
-1
```

The code matches what've seen in other online samples, but the list item isn't created, but it doesn't raise an error.

In my list, Title and Project Code are required and I am using a custom content type that I created in the Admin portal and then included in the 'Projects' list.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution that works.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $km_site -ClientId $clientid -ClientSecret $secret -WarningAction Ignore

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.listItem]$list_item = Add-PnPListItem -List "Projects" -ContentType "Project Info" -Values @{"Title" = $title; "_ExtendedDescription"=$desc; "Project_x0020_Code"=$code}
```